# FireFox overflow bug#550882: (overflow:hidden) to (overflow:visible) with script = no scrollbars

Tags: firefox

I ran into a problem recently and found out that this is a bona-fide bug in FireFox 3.6.x.

If you set up your page's initial CSS overflow property on the body tag to be `hidden`, then change the style value via a script (like javascript) to `visible` FireFox does NOT render the scrollbars on screen. You can still move the window using keyboard, but there are no visible scrollbars at all. Neither refreshing nor resizing the page will get them to render.

So, I have to set the initial value CSS definition to `visible||auto` and THEN change the value to hidden||visible as needed. It caused me a few extra lines of code for other purposes as well, so I know this is not the optimal solution.

Has anyone else out there run into this bug?
If so, how did you work around it?
I want to be able to have an elegant solution that works in as many as browsers as possible.

Here is the [link to the bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=550882). It says it is fixed but I am still running into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assign the initial value to be "scroll", and immediately change it as soon as the page loads. Making sure to adjust my page window as needed upon the page ready event.

Comment: accepted because it is the only answer I got in weeks... so why not?